# How does pandas.DataFrame.sum() physically work?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

How does `.sum()` method in `pandas.DataFrame` physically work?

I'm calculating proportion of salary of each individual staffworker to the total of all salaries.

The CSV has 33,000 rows.

The below function, add_proportion, goes row by row and reads each worker's salary, then divides it by `salary.sum()` for all rows.

Question: In each of these 33,000 cycles, does `salary.sum()` do its own 33,000 cycles to calculate the total over and over?

Asking because in this case the total number of cycles would be 1 billion (33,000 times 33,000), which should result in some kind of a delay. But there is no delay, the function runs instantly.

Therefore, does `.sum()` calculate the total during the first cycle only and then reuses the value?

Thanks.

```
import pandas as pd

staff = pd.read_csv('staff.csv', names = ['name', 'salary'])

def add_proportion(group):
    group['proportion'] = salary / salary.sum()
    return group
```

Comment: How do you call your function? What's `salary`? Do you mean `staff['salary']`?

Answer (score 0):

`pandas` uses `numpy` under the hood.  In `numpy`, the behavior of applying operations between differently sized arrays is called [broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

It depends how you are calling your `add_proportion` function, but the call to `sum` *should* only happen once for the whole dataframe (or once per group if you are doing a `groupby(...).apply(add_proportion)` for example).

Answer (score -1):

Each sum is thread, which means that all the sums are made at the same time , they are parallelized.

The limit is your RAM that determine the number of parallel process you are allowed to have.

For more information, I would advice https://medium.com/@bfortuner/python-multithreading-vs-multiprocessing-73072ce5600b

Comment: I am not sure this answer is accurate or helpful. Can you please cite some more info and references for this?

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct.  It's more likely that pandas/numpy uses something like SIMD under the hood instead of threads.

Comment: I agree that what i said is not accurate, it was a false assumption based on the analyse between numpy arrays and panda arrays

https://penandpants.com/2014/09/05/performance-of-pandas-series-vs-numpy-arrays/